# MySQL Architecture and Multiple User Types

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am designing a database for a system that has more than one user type (user, admin, superuser). I have read up on multiple ways of dealing with handling the different user account types and the one that makes the me is to have a single table of "user" with the common fields and then carry a "userType" value to point to the correct corresponding table for additional information.

The one thing that stares out at me is that if I ever want more specific data about that user, I would have to run a second query based on the userType. It does not seem possible to get at the more specific user information initially.

I would have to do some kind of case logic based on the userType (type = 1 -> go to user table, type = 2-> go to admin table) and then hit the db again. Am I overlooking something here?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you should be able to query the user table while doing a left join on the admin table, right?

Comment: i can but the point is that I would not know which table to look into for additional information. Say I have any number of user types, I would not know which table to go to in order to get the more role specific information. 
The only way I can think of making it work would be if I had a Type table where I carried the typeId and the tableName and joined that on the query...

Comment: Sounds like you need to map out what info you want to store for each type. Then you can decide if its necc to keep it in separate tables.

Comment: I know all the data that has to go into each table and there are requirements for separate tables because the user roles are pretty different. The question is really about whether it is possible to format a query that would be able to evaluate the value of a field in the same query or whether it would be necessary to store the table name elsewhere so that it can be accessed in a join.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use multiple tables then you can view them all in one query either using UNION in your select or join each to the initial table and pick out which columns to display using an if statement.

Comment: So your suggestion is that they always (left) join all the tables for every possible user type? That does sound like the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the most logical solution for this problem is doing it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
LEFT JOIN admin ON admin.user_id = user.user_id AND user.type = 'admin'
LEFT JOIN superuser ON superuser.user_id = user.user_id AND user.type = 'superuser'
```

You'll get `NULL` for users which aren't admin/superuser and rows for those that are. And if you don't need the extra fields in all cases than you should simply omit them from the query (although some databases like Postgres will automatically do this if you don't select the fields).